# layout does not fill parent

Tags: android, css, android-layout, width

I have a `TableRow` that expands through the width of the screen and within that `TableRow` i have a `ListView` whose `layout_width` is set to `match_parent`, but it still does not expand through the width of the screen. It was working properly but eversince i introduced 2 buttons in the next `TableRow` the problem occured. I have set `layout_span` property to 2 and still doesn't work. Here's my xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/saltnpepper">

        <TableRow 
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:gravity="center">

            <TextView 
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="#FF00FF" 
            android:layout_span="2"/>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow 
        android:layout_weight="4" 
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" 
        android:background="#FF00FF" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ListView 
            android:id="@+id/list1" 
            android:layout_span="2" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">
            </ListView>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow 
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:gravity="center" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

            <Button 
            android:id="@+id/btnAddToOrder" 
            android:text="Add To Order"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width = "match_parent" 
            android:background="#FF00FF" />

            <Button 
            android:id="@+id/btnProceed" 
            android:text="Order Now" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width = "match_parent"        
            android:background="#FF00FF" />

        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
```

I have tried changing background colors so i am sure the exact problem is with `ListView` not expanding the whole width of screen whereas `TableRow` (middle one) is perfectly fitting the screen

Comment: Where is your list item layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFF00"
    android:layout_weight="3">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="#FF00FF"
            android:layout_span="4"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:gravity="center">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="#FF00FF"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ListView android:id="@+id/list1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                >
            </ListView>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </TableRow>




    <TableRow
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <Button android:id="@+id/btnAddToOrder"
            android:text="Add To Order"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width = "match_parent" 
            android:background="#FF00FF" />
        <Button android:id="@+id/btnProceed" 
            android:text="Order Now"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width = "match_parent"
            android:background="#FF00FF" />

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

It is showing output as you want.

Comment: Thanks! It did work :D..So you put the listview into relative layout and set weight=1 that's what was missing..i suppose..

Comment: You should explain what was wrong with the original and what have you changed and why.